# How to return an array from jQuery ajax success function properly?

Tags: jquery, ajax, scope, return

```
TheObject = {    
    getArray: function(){
        var groups = new Array;
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "link.php",
              success: function (data){
                  var counter = 0;
                  $('g',data).each(function(){    
                      var group_name = $(this).find("name").text();
                      var group_id = $(this).find("id").text();
                      var group = {
                         id: group_id,
                         name: group_name
                      }
                      groups[counter] = group;
                      counter++;
                  });
                  return groups;
              }
         });
     }

}
```

And when I try to call this method:

```
var a = TheObject.getArray();
alert(a);
```

It returns 'undefined'.
I cant figure out where is the problem. The array gets created inside the success function but I'am unable to return it properly.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your code, you are looking for `groups` using procedural coding after the ajax call was made. The main problem is that you are looking for `groups` before the ajax call is complete.

Another problem is that you are returning groups to the `success()` function, but the `TheObject.getArray()` function returns nothing.

So you need to bring in the callback into the ajax function like this:

```
TheObject = {
    getArray: function(callback) {
        var groups = new Array;
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "link.php",
              success: function (data){
                  var counter = 0;
                  $('g',data).each(function(){    
                      var group_name = $(this).find("name").text();
                      var group_id = $(this).find("id").text();
                      var group = {
                         id: group_id,
                         name: group_name
                      }
                      groups[counter] = group;
                      counter++;
                  });
                  callback.call(this,groups);
              }
         });
     }
}

TheObject.getArray(function(a) {
    // this code runs when the ajax call is complete
    alert(a);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

A very simple version of David's example.

```
TheObject = {
    getArray: function(callback) { 
        $.ajax({
              cache: true,
              type: "GET",
              url: "http://www.domain.com/core/domains.php",
              success: function (data){ 
                  callback.call(this,data);
              }
         });
     }
}

TheObject.getArray(function(data) {
    javascript: console.log(data);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `push` on the array. Also you want to create a type called Group and then create a new group in the loop and then push it into the array.

Comment: Please read the question. I don't have a problem with creating the array. The problem is I don't know how to get it outside of the success function.